# How can you require project to be specified in call to gcloud?

Tags: gcloud

Consider the case in which some script and/or Makefile is running a series of gcloud commands.  While waiting for those commands to complete, the user goes to another shell and changes the gcloud configuration to refer to a different project.  Hopefully, the script/Makefile was written well enough that all necessary gcloud invocations include "--project", and no harm will be done by stray gcloud commands running in the wrong project.  Is there any gcloud configuration that can help to prevent problems in that scenario?  Perhaps a config setting to force gcloud commands to fail if `--project` is not specified?

Answer (score 2):

You could deal with this issue by using multiple gcloud configurations,  each configuration can have a different value for "project". Only one configurations can be active at a time so you would still have the same problem, however you can activate  a configurations for a single gcloud invocations with the --configuration flag. This means that if your Makefile uses the --configuration flag for each gcloud invocation it would be immune to the user going to another shell and changing the project as long as the user was not using the same configuration that the Makefile was using. "gcloud topic configurations" has documentation about how to use configurations.